# How to allow user to enter only number and letters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am aware of using regex, but is that possible to not use it? this is my text field username in the modal form. i want to allow user to enter only number and letter and no white space and special character included.

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.username.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';">
 <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="username" ng-model="user.username" required>
   <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" ng-class="addUser.username.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
</div>
```

this is the controller part.

```
    $scope.users = [{
    username: "a"
}];


$scope.addUser = function(user) {
    $dialog.open({
        showClose: false,
        closeByEscape: true,
        template: 'views/user/user-user-add.html',
        controller: ['$scope', function($dialogScope) {
            $dialogScope.isLoading = false;
            $dialogScope.errorMessage = "";
            $dialogScope.title = "New User";
            $dialogScope.user = {
                username: ""

            };
```

appreciate if anyone could help me.

Comment: I have no idea about AngularJS but there is a HTML5 attribute called "pattern". Read more on http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: i tried to include this pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]". but it seems doesnt match what i want. what do i missing? @Inuka

Comment: I added my idea to the answers. Have a look please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

```
$(function() {
    $('#username').on( 'keydown', function( e ) {
        if( !$( this ).data( "value" ) )
             $( this ).data( "value", this.value );
    });
    $('#username').on( 'keyup', function( e ) {
        if (!/^[_0-9a-z]*$/i.test(this.value))
            this.value = $( this ).data( "value" );
        else
            $( this ).data( "value", null );
    });
});
```

Add `id="username"` attribute to your textfield as well please.

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r4fY5/1/)

**Edit**

If you have multiple username fields, instead of `id="username"` use `class="username"` and change the Javascript to `$('.username')`. So it would work on multiple textfields.

Comment: is that possible if i just want to set pattern at html without involving the controller? just link in this link? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: As I said, I have 0 knowledge about AngularJS but this is Javascript and this should work with your code. Also if you inject a textfield from ajax like what you're doing now, this code will work as long as you've put this on the master JS file. Make a backup of the project and give it a try please. :)

Comment: @sue I'm glad I helped you. Up vote the answer if you like. :) I have loads of them just in-case if I need them in future. :)